# utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 377: invalid start byte

Tags: c, matrix, utf-8

The program is to accept a matrix and an integer and replace all the elements with asterisk('*') other than the elements present in upper left and right triangle and lower right and left triangle of size k.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, x, i, j;
    // Inputs
    printf("n: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    char a[n][n], b[n][n];
    printf("Enter the matrix elements\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%c\n", &a[i][j]);
            b[i][j] = '*';
        }
    }
    printf("x: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &x);
    printf("x: %d\n",x);
    
    // Implementation
    // Top right and left triangles 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < x - i; j++)
        {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
        for (j = n - 1; j >= (n - x) + i; j--)
        {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    // Bottom right and left triangles
    int c = 0;
    for (i = n - 1; i >= (n - x); i--)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < x - c; j++)
        {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
        for (j = n - 1; j >= (n-x) + c; j--)
        {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
        c++;
    }
    
    // Printing the mat
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%c ", b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program works for inputs 1 through 8... I didn't try for inputs past 8 because its was tedious enough to type 64 elements, but when I submitted the program it showed that for test case of matrix size 50 the result was an error, specifically **'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 377: invalid start byte**
The program works fine for inputs 1 to 8. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You should check if `x` holds a valid value. If it is too large you might access your array beyond its boundaries.

Comment: x value for that case was 10